# Scaling the scroll wheel

Tags: cocoa

I have a very wide NSView set as the document of an NSScrollView. When I am zoomed in (by setting the cliprect bounds rectangle) swiping left and right on my magic mouse scroll the expected amount.

But when zoomed out (when the bounds rect is nearly the same size of the frame rect) left/right swiping is frustrating because of the small step distance has almost no effect.

I'd like to scale the step distance used for wheel scrolling. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not modify the clip view's bounds to scale your view. Instead, you should scale the document view of the scroll view, using the `‑scaleUnitSquareToSize:` method of `NSView`:

```
NSView* docView = [yourScrollView documentView];
[docView scaleUnitSquareToSize:NSMakeSize(2.0, 2.0)];
[docView setNeedsDisplay:YES];
```

If you scale the clip view then you will change the way the scroll view calculates the scroller behavior.